# How to make celllabel text bold on the basis of flag coming from server

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

I have asked this question before that how to change colour of `UITableViewCell` on the basis of flags it was done but when i am changing font of label on the basis of flag it was not done below is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` sample code for it kindly tell that what I am mistaking

```
if([[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"messageRead"] intValue]==0)
    {

          cell.titlename.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI-bold" size:15];
    }
    else
    {
          cell.titlename.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI" size:15];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this line of code:

```
cell.titlename.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10];
```

Change the font size as per your project requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Few points you need to check:

1) Make sure condition works fine

2) If its going into the Bold condition & still not working try using other font type to make sure there is no font issue

3) Try to use this fonts in other control to make sure its supported

Hope it will help you.